# Why was this circuits question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, homework-and-exercises, reopen

See: [Find the Thevenin's Voltage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611417/)

The question asker seems a little forward, but there is a deeper question he asks if you read his entire submission, an answer to which would be very typical of SE.

Seems a bit unfair - not even a comment was left saying how his question might be rephrased/improved.
Any thoughts?

Comment: the question can be summed up as “I got confused” and it’s definitely a homework problem.

Comment: You should be able to see the reason for closure (our homework-and-exercises policy) at the top of the post. We recently edited the closure reasons so that an explanatory text should be visible to all users. Do you not see a closure reason on this post?

Comment: A comment *was* left, saying how the question might be improved: the closure banner has links to the homework policy, which explains what the boundaries are.

Answer (score 12):

The title of the question is "Find the Thevenin's Voltage," and the first line is "Please solve this." In its current form, it is a straightforward homework question.

If there is a deeper, on-topic question contained inside, then the question should be edited to contain *only* that question.